# Which hadoop version to use?

Tags: hadoop

Both hadoop in action & the definitive guide, both have built their foundation from the mapred classes. And most of those classes have been deprecated in 0.20.2. The signatures of the new classes are different. Can anyone tell me about the various changes done. E.g. the partitioner class has been deprecated. How is the new reducer going to provide its feature. Concept changes that happened in 0.20.2

What should i use? On the hadoop wiki, i see
Download
1.0.X - current stable version, 1.0 release
1.1.X - current beta version, 1.1 release
2.X.X - current alpha version
0.23.X - simmilar to 2.X.X but missing NN HA.
0.22.X - does not include security
0.20.203.X - legacy stable version
0.20.X - legacy version

Does that means the mapred classes were deprecated & have been reintroduced. Which hadoop version should i use? 0.20.2 or 1.0.x ?

Answer (score 6):

> Please check this out, it explains the version control of Hadoop development:  http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2012/04/apache-hadoop-versions-looking-ahead-3/
>
> So you can get idea of why it has quite complex versions.
>
> p/s: I'm using v1.0.3 for my system :)

That is an April Fools Day post.  :)

But anyone can agree the versions are misleading at best.